# Isekai manga where the male lead gets help from a goddess and is given two female comrades (a vampire and an angel)

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I’m looking for an isekai manga with a male protagonist, who wears a jacket with a tower emblem on it, and two female comrades (one is a vampire with silver hair and moon clip on it and the other is an angel with golden hair and sun clip on it). Those two were given by a goddess to serve and help him. During the manga he upgrades a dungeon tower with various monsters.

Comment: What does ML mean? Do the emblems mean anything? Why were they given to help him? Was this like a tower defence as a manga? Was he defending against the monsters? What upgrades did he do? What was he protecting? When did you read this? If you have anything else to add you can [edit] that detail into the question itself.

Comment: ML:male lead and tower like symbol(emblem) & they were given to help him live in another world although he was also trained by godess but idk why and I read this between may to June and the dungeon which they capture was highest and strongest said by people of that world it was suggested by some merchant friend when her 2 female companion help them from bandits and monster attack

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the extra information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is *[Tou no Kanri o Shite Miyou](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tou-no-kanri-wo-shite-miyou)*, also known as *Let's manage the tower*.

The main character dies and is taken to a goddess, who gives him new clothes, including a cape that has a clasp with a tower emblem on it.  He then appears where two women are fighting, one is an angel, the other seems to be a fallen angel(she has black angel wings).  The angel has golden hair, though i don't see a sun clip.  The fallen angel has silver hair with a crescent moon clip in the front.  A little later he looks at their statuses and, at least in the translation i found, they are a part of the 'Sunlight Race' and 'Moonlight Race'.

The group then travels a bit and comes across a merchant, and the two women save him. Afterwards they travel with the merchant's group to town and register as adventurers. The spend a few weeks raising their ranks, then one of the adventurers who had been with the merchant mentions the towers to the group. There are towers that people conquered on other continents, but none on their continent had been conquered because they were too difficult. The group then decides to conquer the largest tower on the continent.

After they conquer the tower, the main character becomes the new master of tower.  They then spend their time managing the tower.  The eventually bring in various groups to reside on different levels of the tower, including a group of vampires.