# Isekai manga about a main character who has an angel companion

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for an isekai manga I read long time ago. The only thing I only remember is that the main character has an angel companion, and that he summoned two goddesses in front of many people.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is *[Tou no Kanri o Shite Miyou](https://myanimelist.net/manga/115369/Tou_no_Kanri_wo_Shitemiyou)* or *Let's manage the tower*, also the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235295/isekai-manga-where-the-male-lead-gets-help-from-a-goddess-and-is-given-two-femal/).

The main character has 2 companions, one of which is an angel.  Eventually he build a church and invites the rulers and important people from the nearby countries to the opening of the church. During the ceremony blessing the church, he summons 3 goddesses to bless the church in front of the crowd.

[image: 3 Goddesses congratulating their summoner]