# Manga where the main character is trained by one or more goddesses and is eventually told that he has become a god himself

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character somehow gets into gods realm and is trained by all the goddess and reincarnated into otherworld with two girls created by the goddess. There, he begins an adventure to get the tower, where he establishes his own tower, then he creates tools to communicate with gods. He tries to travel to gods realm and when he gets there, the goddess says he has become a god.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Isekai manga where the male lead gets help from a goddess and is given two female comrades (a vampire and an angel)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235295/isekai-manga-where-the-male-lead-gets-help-from-a-goddess-and-is-given-two-femal)

Answer (score 2):

I reread this today. The name is [*Tou no Kanri wo Shitemiyou*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/115369/Tou_no_Kanri_wo_Shitemiyou) (AKA. *Let's Manage the Tower*)

> Kosuke is killed by a truck, his soul is lost in a garden with two
> beautiful girls. The owner of the place will let him choose whether he
> will be reborn or summoned to another world, and he maintains the
> summons. In this new world, the main two girls who were created by the
> owner of the garden to help him find the mystery behind the world: a
> dungeon tower. Will he be able to become the owner of this tower and
> manage it?
>
> [image]

Comment: Removed infringing link and replaced with non-infringing link

Comment: If you're the person who wrote the original question, you can [contact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact) a moderator to combine your two accounts. That will allow you to mark this answer as 'accepted'